# close horizontal drop-down menu on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working off some code for a drop-down menu I found here on stack overflow: http://jsfiddle.net/jhoffm34/VbtuC/

I have a jquery drop-down menu that expands on click. I am trying to use document.onmousedown to get the menu to close when I click on "Categories" for a second time, but it is just reopening the menu right away. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Working demos**
http://jsfiddle.net/RguMu/show
http://jsfiddle.net/RguMu/
http://jsfiddle.net/UK9Qt/ - only when category is clicked show and hide

So on second click, your menu will be closed now:

use `is(':visible')`

Another suggestion, you don't need so many properties.  Just do `show` and `hide`, rest you know your requirement better.

**jQuery code**

```
if(submenu.is(':visible')){
    submenu.hide();
    return false;
}
```

**Full code**

```
var timeout = 999999;
var closetimer = 0;
var ddmenuitem = 0;

function jsddm_open(event) {
    jsddm_canceltimer();
    jsddm_close();
    var submenu = $(this).find('ul');

    if(submenu.is(':visible')){
        submenu.hide();
        return false;
    }

    if (submenu) {
        ddmenuitem = submenu.css('visibility', 'visible');
        ddmenuitem = submenu.css('position', 'relative');
        submenu.show();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

function jsddm_close() {
    if (ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.css('visibility', 'hidden');
    if (ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.css('position', 'fixed');
}

function jsddm_timer() {
    closetimer = window.setTimeout(jsddm_close, timeout);
}

function jsddm_canceltimer() {
    if (closetimer) {
        window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
        closetimer = null;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#jsddm li').bind('click', jsddm_open);
    $('#jsddm > li').bind('mouseout', jsddm_timer);
    $('#jsddm > li').bind('mouseover', jsddm_canceltimer);
    $('#jsddm li').find('ul').hide();

});

document.onmousedown = jsddm_close;
```